# How to hide 0 bars in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts bar that some bars have zero value. I want to remove the gap of zero values, For example in the following chart I want to hide the gap between 14.9 and 26.7. How can I do this? I pass null value for the zero values.

For example it is part of the data I pass to highcharts for zero values:

```
name: 'some name',
color:'#7ef279',
data:  [null,1,null]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post some of your code/data?

Comment: You can use workaround like here: http://jsfiddle.net/zmktekak/14/

Comment: @SebastianBochan Is it possible to remove the blank or gap or not? I want to stick the bars not distribute gap between them.

Comment: @Majid, the best way would be to remove the `null` points from your data before plotting if you want to remove them from chart altogether.

Comment: @Majid you can set grouPadding / pointPadding as 0 in the [plotOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.groupPadding)

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks a lot for your comments. They were very helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250844/highcharts-remove-gap-column-with-zero-value