# Remove reserved white space for empty groups in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using the "[Stacked and grouped column](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped)" chart.

Sometimes there is no data in a certain group, and the respective stacks are skipped by passing `null` values. I would like the chart to adjust accordingly by **not** showing the white space that seems to be reserved for the group.

In the screenshot below, there is only one group for "Two", yet there is a lot of white space underneath. How do I close the gap?

[image: Highcharts empty column]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I think you can modify solution from this topic in your case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250844/highcharts-remove-gap-column-with-zero-value
If you think it is good idea to have this functionality in your chart, you can ask for it on Highcharts uservoice: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/
The most popular ideas gets to be implemented.